# What does the 'jekyll 2.4.0 | Error: Permission denied - /sys/fs/ext4/sda1/trigger_fs_error' mean

Tags: permissions, ext4, github, jekyll

I am trying to run a Custom GitHub Pages with Jekyll, but every time when I run `bundle exec jekyll serve` I get the below error:

> jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  Permission denied - /sys/fs/ext4/sda1/trigger_fs_error

this is what I have tried so far:

```
USERNAME@USERNAME:/var/www/newos$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /var/www/newos/_config.yml
            Source: /
       Destination: /var/www/newos/_site
      Generating... 
jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  No such device or address - /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_-90244180
USERNAME@USERNAME:/var/www/newos$ rm /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_-90244180
USERNAME@USERNAME:/var/www/newos$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /var/www/newos/_config.yml
            Source: /
       Destination: /var/www/newos/_site
      Generating... 
jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  No such device or address - /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_e4e524e7c9589de23a66c7b357f6bf82
USERNAME@USERNAME:/var/www/newos$ rm /tmp/OSL_PIPE_1000_SingleOfficeIPC_e4e524e7c9589de23a66c7b357f6bf82
USERNAME@USERNAME:/var/www/newos$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /var/www/newos/_config.yml
            Source: /
       Destination: /var/www/newos/_site
      Generating... 
jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  No such device or address - /tmp/gpg-qYqBN2/S.gpg-agent
USERNAME@USERNAME:/var/www/newos$ rm /tmp/gpg-qYqBN2/S.gpg-agent
USERNAME@USERNAME:/var/www/newos$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /var/www/newos/_config.yml
            Source: /
       Destination: /var/www/newos/_site
      Generating... 
jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  Permission denied - /sys/fs/ext4/sda1/trigger_fs_error
```

Comment: Could it be that the `source` should be `Source: /var/www/newos`? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `_config.yml` the `source` should list the actual location of the project

```
...
source: /var/www/newos
...
```

Yep, knuckle head mistake.